# Is there a way I can use last-of-type while taking into account elements that are not being displayed due to *ngIf?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a number of repeated elements in a column, and I want to be able to style the very last one and reduce its bottom margin, but this should only happen to the last elements. The elements above it should have a bigger bottom margin.

However any of these elements may be de-rendered using *ngIf, so I need a way to determine whether the last element matches the selector AND if its visible, if so reduce the margin.

```
<div *ngIf="display1" class="element">Element</div>
<div *ngIf="display2" class="element">Element</div>
<div *ngIf="display3" class="element">Element</div>
<div *ngIf="display4" class="element">Element</div>
```

```
.element {
 margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.element:last-of-type:visible {
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Obviously `visible` isn't a pseudo-class, but I need something that would give this sort of functionality while preferable not using Javascript to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a CSS option, you can use css pseudo selector [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) - in your example, if you have a containing element, you can the use the last-child with a specific enough rule to only select the correct element you would like (whatever is not created by ngIf won't be selected by this selector).

If you provide more of the html I would be able to give a more specific example